# unable to load 'rvest' library in RStudio

Tags: r, winapi, rstudio, rvest

Following error encountered:
Loading required package: xml2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xml2’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Shilpa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: package ‘xml2’ could not be loaded

Comment: Failure to resolve dependencies, system probably finding only 32 hit C runtime. Make sure you have 64 bit versions of all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Corruption of one of more .dll files
2. Attempting to mix 32-bit and 64-bit shared libraries.
3. One or more dependencies were simply missing.

Download dependency walker, and use it to check that xml2.dll (and all its dependencies) exist and can be loaded. Similarly for Rcpp.dll. Be sure to use the correct version of dependency walker (32-bit vs 64-bit).